# Saying Kaddish for A Friend

Tags: kaddish

What is the halacha on saying Kaddish for a friend?  It is my understanding that this is not typically done but that there is some precedent for it to occur.

Thank you for your replies.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya Nancy! Thanks for sharing the question. Hope you choose to stick around the site.

Comment: Have to research an answer, and I'm not sure if the one @sabbahillel mentioned is really a dupe. In my shul, and a number of other that I have attended, the rabbi and a few others say Kaddish for deceased congregants (Aka "those that died during service" :-o :-0 ), as usually no relative is saying Kaddish for them. I assume that you mean "daily" Kaddish during the 11 months of mourning and not Kaddish on a person's Yahrtzeit. There may be somewhat different rules, here.

Comment: @DanF From my experience, the rules for a Yahrtzeit are the same as for the 11 months. The main point for the year was because that tends to be more difficult and is also when it starts.

Comment: The question is saying Kaddish for someone for a friend who may or may not even be Jewish.  The congregation I attend during the winter months encourages people to say Kaddish for someone close to the congregant who has recently died.  I am not familiar with this practice at all.  Is is acceptable to say Kaddish for a friend at the time of the person's passing?

Answer (score 0):

There's custom/minhag and there's halakha.  The custom with which I was raised is that you don't say your first kaddish for anyone outside the relationships for which you mourn and say kaddish - parents, siblings, children, spouse.  if you've already said kaddish and there's only, say, female survivors, you may say it.

BUT that's only a minhag.

Comment: Even if there's male relatives, often another will say Kaddish if none of the relatives go to shul 3 times a day or if someone who needs to say Kaddish will be traveling and won't have a minyan

Answer (score 0):

My husband says kadish form many people who do not have others to say kadish for them he says it is a big mitzva but also a responsibility, to make sure your husband gets to the minyan on time, and does not miss a day.  so that the niftar can get the full benefit of the year.  for sure it would be better if the persons son said it and not a man not related to him.  hope this helps... my condolences

Comment: Shepard, welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks for your first answer! If you haven’t done so already, you should take a look at the [tour](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour). Please consider [registering](//judaism.stackexchange.com/users/signup-unregistered) your account, to [enable](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) more site features, including voting.

I hope you find more Q&A of interest and stay learning with us!

Comment: Also, MY is different from other sites you know. Maybe you will be interested by something I wrote to help you understand the site ["A beginner’s guide to MY - How is this site different from other Judaism sites”](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501)
 ?